# understanding windows time configuration

Tags: windows, time, time-synchronization

I wish to set external time source for all Vms and HyperVs in several domains. Most of the systems are windows Server 2012 R2 or Server 2016. I have been reading a lot of explanations and I somehow figured how to do it. My problem is proving my configuration. 
here below is a configration output from a non-DC system.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 30000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: NT5DS (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

So when I see "NT5DS (Local)" I know that system is taking time from DC but thats not enough for me. So I wish to know nearly every line with possible options here so I can understand background and affect of settings I make. Unfortunately I could not find any document that explains.Can anyone please explain or provide a link to such explanation?

Comment: ...what's wrong with the [official docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings)? You should also set the time on your DCs/ internal timeservers and set all clients to get their time from them.

Comment: It does not answer many things. When I work on the DC for example I set an external source
`Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: pool.ntp.org (Local)
NtpServer (Local)`
why does it show local? or why does it show two NTP servers altough I set one external? Normally it is done so that DC are the time sources in a domain but we decided to have some systems use external time sources due to location, nt latency etc.

Comment: So you want to sync all of your domain joined machines to an external time source? If so, why?

Comment: we wish to standardize our VM creation process regardless of machines joining domain or not. Thats why we wish to make VMs as independent as possible. Time is just of course one of the items in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It displays (Local) due to it is the result of local configuration. If it were configured in Group Policy, it would display (Policy). If you specified the /verbose flag, for settings not configured it would display (Undefined or NotUsed).